# Why do these two for loops give different results?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
int num=1025;
for (int i = num; i<1030; System.out.println("i =" + i), i++); //loop 1

System.out.println(""); // for spacing results

for (int i = num; i<1030; System.out.println("i =" + i)) { //loop 2
    i++;
}
```

You can run them on your java compiler and you would see what am saying.

Comment: thats what happen when you didnt follow the recomended _form_ of the `for` loop

Comment: Thanks Guys.. This is to expand our understanding of the for loop.. Good to hear some people didn't know such a syntax exist. @Eran Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's the first time I see `println` in the increment expression of a for loop.

The difference is due to the fact that in the second loop, `i++` is performed before the increment expression, so `println` prints the new value of `i`.

In the first loop, `i` is incremented in the increment expression, but after the `println`, so the previous value of `i` is printed.

Comment: "It's the first time I see println in the increment expression of a for loop." +1

Comment: @reto I didn't even know this was valid syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

Because:

- loop1 prints `i` before it increments it,
- loop2 prints `i` after it increments it.

In a for loop

```
  for (<initial> ; <test> ; <post> ) {
       <body>
  }
```

The loop `<body>` is executed before the `<post>` clause of the `for` loop.  In your examples, you have the increment of `i` in different places ...

---

Aside: both forms of your loop are poor style ... with the `print` statement at that point.  Don't ever do that in real code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your first for loop works:

- Initialize i to 1025
- check the condition i<1030
- print and then increment i and then repeat from step above

Note print statement followed by increment of i value.

This is how your second for loop works:

- Initialize i to 1025
- check the condition i<1030
- increment i
- Print value of i (note it will be i + 1)  and then repeat from step 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of for loop:-

> The Boolean expression is evaluated. If it is true, the body of the loop is executed. After the body of the for loop executes, the flow of control jumps back up to the update statement.

Hence for

```
for (int i = num; i<1030; System.out.println("i =" + i), i++);
```

First it will execute `System.out.println("i =" + i)`(1st statement in increment condition of for loop) then it will do `i++`(2nd statement in increment condition of for loop)

In case of

```
for (int i = num; i<1030; System.out.println("i =" + i))
```

First it will execute `i++`(the body of for loop) then it will run `System.out.println("i =" + i)` (which is the increment condition in this case)

Answer (score 0):

```
for loop    working is illustrated as below.

    for ( declaration ; condition ; update action ) {
        //for block
    }
```

below is the order in which the for loop is executed.
1. declaration
2. condition check
3. for block execution
4. update action.

In your case the println statement in second loop is executed after the i++ operator. Hence the value is incremented to 1026 before it is being printed on the console.

Answer (score 0):

The for 2nd for loop will treat `System.out.println("i =" + i)` as your update statement of the for loop and increment in `i` is done before this execution.
To explain it better consider the structure of any for loop :

`for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update){
   //Statements
}`

The initialisation step is executed first and only once. Then the next Boolean_expression is evaluated. If found true the body will be executed, if false then the loop terminates.
After the body executes the control jumps back to the update statement and executed.

so in the above code `System.out.println("i =" + i)` is treated as the update statement and executed last, thats why the output is

i =1025
i =1026
i =1027
i =1028
i =1029

i =1026
i =1027
i =1028
i =1029
i =1030